# Create a plugin in wordpress is including blank space

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I am crating a wordpress plugin with ajax.

My main plugin file (myplugin.php) is:

```
function loadScreen(){
   wp_enqueue_style( 'files', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'css/style.css' );
   wp_enqueue_script( 'files', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/ajax.js' );
   require( dirname( __FILE__ ).'/html-template.php');
}

add_shortcode("loadmyplugin", "loadScreen");
```

and html-template.php is:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>    
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

        var option = '';
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: URL,
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'GET',
        }).done(function(data) { 

            for(var spec in data){
                options += '<option value='+spec+'>'+data[spec]+'</option>';
            }

            jQuery('select#option-list').append(options);              
        });           
    });
</script>

<div class="et_pb_section et_section_regular">

    <div class="et_pb_row ">
        <select id="option-list"></select>
    </div>        
    ...       
</div>
```

I am also using Divi to build content page and I would like to use my plugin from a shortcode [loadmyplugin].

My plugin is working, the only problem is that my plugin is including some blank space in the page edit mode [image1] and it's loading in the beginning of the page [image2], but I would like it loads where I created the module for it.

I think I am missing something about add_filter or add_action, but I am not sure, can someone help me?

image1:
[image: image1]

image2:
[image: image2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "require" produces output when shortcode is called, it should "return" your html instead.

Easy fix:

```
function loadScreen(){
   wp_enqueue_style( 'files', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'css/style.css' );
   wp_enqueue_script( 'files', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/ajax.js' );
   // start to capture output into buffer
   ob_start(); 
   require( dirname( __FILE__ ).'/html-template.php');
   // return captured output and end buffering
   return ob_get_clean();
}

add_shortcode("loadmyplugin", "loadScreen");
```

Comment: Thank you! It helped me.